# Preserve leading whitespace on the first row of a YAML multiline string

Tags: yaml

I have the below data that I wish to import:

```yaml
songs:
  -
    title: After Hours
    artist: The Velvet Underground
    body: |
             Bb        G7
      If you close the door
          Cm                  F
      The night could last forever
                Bb       G7
      Leave the sunshine out
          Cm           F
      And say hello to never
```

I'd like to preserve the 7 leading spaces before `Bb` on the first row.

Is there a way I can do this?

I've put my hacky workaround up as a temporary answer, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per e.g. http://yaml-multiline.info/ you can add an *indentation indicator* in cases where it can't accurately be guessed from the first line:

```yaml
songs:
  -
    title: After Hours
    artist: The Velvet Underground
    body: |2
             Bb        G7
      If you close the door
          Cm                  F
      The night could last forever
                Bb       G7
      Leave the sunshine out
          Cm           F
      And say hello to never
```

The `body` here would be parsed to

```
"       Bb        G7\nIf you close the door\n    Cm                  F\nThe night could last forever\n          Bb       G7\nLeave the sunshine out\n    Cm           F\nAnd say hello to never\n"
```

Comment: I'm afraid that only works if *all* lines are to have their whitespace kept. It does not apply only to the first line, unfortunately.

Comment: @Nossidge is that _not_ what you want? Surely the lines starting Cm and Bb should _all_ retain the initial whitespace? Perhaps you could [edit] to clarify the output you're expecting.

Comment: You're right! I had been attempting to use `|7`, but I should have been using `|2`, as that is the "baseline" indent. Thank you so much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to add a non-indented first line:

```yaml
    body: |
      BODY
             Bb        G7
      If you close the door
          Cm                  F
      The night could last forever
```

And after the file has been read, I remove this line from the array.

But I'd much prefer not to have to compromise the YAML data in this way.